# Export Solr document meta info to MySQL

Tags: mysql, solr

I am a newbie experimenting with Solr. What I would like to do is to take advantage of the extracted document meta data and place them into MySQL so I can save some work of calling Tika directly to do the same thing.

My question is whether or not there is a simple way to have Solr export the document meta data directly into MySQL database?

Comment: what do you mean by Solr metadata?

Comment: It's document meta data in Solr. These document meta data are very useful to characterize documents which I'd really love to import into MySQL for document cataloging purposes.